# what should be done first optimization or feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, optimization

I would like to know whether hyperparameter optimization should be done before feature selection or after.

If I do it before feature selection, I guess, I will choose better features (as the classifier is tuned).

But most pipelines on internet (google for machine learning pipeline) always put optimization at the end.

So, what is it recommended? What is a better procedure to do?

Comment: A classifier can only be tuned using data and data is described by features. Therefore you first chose features and then optimize hyperparameters (such as by crossvalidation). Could you provide examples for both cases? (links to tutorials, papers, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just googled for "machine learning pipeline" and checked the images.